# What's the japanese word for manual/building instruction

Tags: translation

I want to search the internet for an instruction for building a traditional kyudo quiver (矢筒). So far my search term is "ビル命令 矢筒 弓道" but I "ビル命令" seems to be no good translation for instruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ビル means 'a building', not 'building' as in 'to build something'. 命令 is an order or command. ビル命令 is gobbledygook.

自作 is the word for 'self-made'. Or you can use the other words that you have along with 作り方 (how to make).

There are a lot of resources out there.

Answer (score 2):

The Japanese word which naturally came to my mind was 組み{くみ}立て{たて}, although it may be more about assembling than building.

Anyway, googling 矢筒の組み立て gave me a link to [矢筒​【イカヨプ・イカヨピコロ】 - アイヌ文化振興・研究推進機構](https://www.frpac.or.jp/manual/files/2008_19.pdf) which looks quite appropriate (page 34: 矢筒を組み立てる).